# Java - take name from string

Tags: java, string

I'm developing a Java application that make some statistic stuff.

This application take all data from a .txt file which is supplied by the user.
The first line of that file contains the name of the sets of data that follows like this:

> velx,vely,velz
>
> //various data

I need to analyze that first line and retrieve the three name of variables, I correctly get the first two but I'm not able to get the last one.

There the code to get names:

```
public ArrayList<String> getTitle(){

// the ArrayList originally is not here but in the class intestation
// I copied it here to simplify code's understanding
ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int titleN = 0;

            String line = br.readLine();   //read the first line of file
            String temp; 
            System.out.println(ManageTable.class.getName() + " Line: " + line);
            int c = line.length();
            
            for(int i = 0; i <c; i++){
                if((line.charAt(i) == ',') || **ANOTHER CONDITION** ){
                    temp = sb.toString();
                    System.out.println(ManageTable.class.getName() +" Temp is: " + temp);
                    title.add(temp);
                    System.out.println(ManageTable.class.getName() + " Title added");
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                }else{
                    sb.append(line.charAt(i));
                }
            }   
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ManageTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return title;
    }
```

I need to add a second condition to the if statement in order to find out when the line is ended and save the last name, even if its not followed by ','
I tried using:

```
if((line.charAt(i) == ',') || (i==c))
```

but from the name I get, always miss a character.
How can I check  the end of the line and so get the full name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If line contains just three names separated by comma, you can do

```
String[] names = line.split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for all this looping. You can just split the line around the comma to get an array:

```
String[] names = line.split(",");
```